# RelationNotFoundException in RelationNotFoundException.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

each product `hasMany` property.

when I use `with` function:

```
dd(Product::with(ProductProperty::class)->get());
```

I got this error :

```
RelationNotFoundException in RelationNotFoundException.php 
Call to undefined relationship [App\Models\ProductProperty] on model [App\Models\Product].
```

---

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';


    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id' ,'brand_id' , 'title', 'price', 'current_buy','max_buy','min_buy_per_bill',
        'max_buy_per_bill','count','off','seri','short_description','long_description',
    ];



    public function ProductProperty()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductProperty');
    }
}
```

---

```
class ProductProperty extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products_properties';

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id' ,'parent_id' , 'title','value', 'price', 'current_buy','max_buy','min_buy_per_bill',
        'max_buy_per_bill','count','off','seri','short_description','long_description',
    ];

    public function Product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code you can't use ::class with the with() function.  The main reason is the ::class will return the full path with namespace.

`Product::with(ProductProperty::class)->get();` is incorrect.

Replace it with `Product::with('ProductProperty')->get();`